# what is the name of following refactoring operation?

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring

At first I have code like this

```
  private  void example(){
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override public void onClick(View view) {
        //some code
      }
    });
  }
```

and then get code like this

```
  private  void example(){
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(backListener);
  }

  View.OnClickListener backListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View view) {
      //some code
    }
  };
```

Comment: You are extracting an inline anonymous class and replacing it with formally defined anonymous class (I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is simply "Extract -> Field" (Ctrl-Alt-F in Windows/Linux keymaps)